# Libreoffice version not up to date

Tags: raspbian, apt, arm, packages

The current Libreoffice version seems to be 7.2.2, but on my Raspberry Pi it's 6.1.5.2. I understand that maybe the ARM version of Libreoffice is a bit behind, but this can't be right.
I used `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` multiple times.I also tried reinstalling but the package seems to be stuck at 6.1. Any ideas, what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's correct for RpiOS Buster.  On Bullseye it moves to 7.0.4:

https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

RpiOS is just a repackaging of Debian with a few extra bits.

When using that web package search, buster = oldstable, bullseye = stable, although RpiOS lagged behind Debian for this release by about ~3 months.

Comment: I suppose I could try a different distro, as I already grew tired of Raspbian anyway. I'll try Manjaro ARM now I think.